# Mac OS: How to control which characters the cursor jumps to on 'Option' + '←/→'

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editing, productivity

In most operating systems, including Mac OS, pressing `Option`/`Control` + `Left/Right Arrow Key` permits to skip the cursor position from word to word. Strictly speaking, this command skips the cursor to the next word boundary.

The essence of my question is: Where does Mac OS specify which characters constitute a word boundary?

I am assuming there is a definition somewhere in the operating system that governs which characters the cursor will jump to (e.g., a regular expression or definition of which set of characters form the set of non-word characters).

I would like to modify this definition. When I edit a file name like '123_Name_Date.txt' on pressing `Option` + `→` the cursor will jump from the beginning of the file name directly to the full-stop. I would, however, like the OS to consider the underscore a non-word character to stop at, too.

So, can I modify or extend the list of characters that Mac OS considers stop-characters in cursor skipping? If so, where and how?